# android how to create a custom xml layout for linearlayout with header text

Tags: android

I tried to create an xml layout that has a border and a header and content like this image, but I have no idea how to create the header.

[image]

can anyone help?

Comment: can you add the image ?

Comment: ok the image is now added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Text here" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headerText"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:text="Text here" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:text="Text here" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headerText"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:text="Text here" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text3"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:text="Text here" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

rectangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:bottom="8dp" android:top="8dp" android:left="8dp" android:right="8dp">
    <shape >
        <stroke android:color="@android:color/black"
                android:width="1dip"/>
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

[image]